# Find the change in value in time series

Tags: java, hashmap, time-series, treemap

I have a map storing the time series data of a person's salary in following format

```
HashMap<Date,Double> salaryHistory;
```

The variable `salaryHistory` can have data from 1AD to even 2100AD.

I am using `subMap` to filter the data from the hashmap, but I am facing a challenge in following scenario

Consider the salary of person like this

```
Jan-01-1969, 100
Jan-01-1979, 200
```

When the user asks the salary between Jan-1-1970 to Jan-1-1972, `subMap` returns "null", but actually it should return 100, because, the person's salary was 100 in 1969 and it never changed till 1979.

Is there an easy way to do this? Like a library.

Kindly please provide your valuable suggestions

Comment: Couldn't your logic just test whether a given date is between two keys and provide the lower of the two values?

Answer (score 1):

I found if you use a SortedMap, instead of a HashMap, you get the behaviour you expect:

```
   Date j1969 = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToDate("1969-01-01");
   Date j1974 = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToDate("1974-01-01");
   Date j1979 = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToDate("1979-01-01");
   Date j1989 = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToDate("1989-01-01");

   TreeMap<Date, Double> treemap = new TreeMap<Date, Double>();
   SortedMap<Date, Double> treemapincl = new TreeMap<Date, Double>();

   // populating tree map
   treemap.put(j1969, 100.0);
   treemap.put(j1979, 200.0);
   treemap.put(j1989, 300.0);

   treemapincl=treemap.subMap(j1969,j1974);
   System.out.println("Sub map values: "+treemapincl);
```

Output:

```
Sub map values: {Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 1969=100.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to necessarily use a `HashMap`, consider replacing it with a `TreeMap` instead.  You can then just use [`TreeMap.floorEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry(K)) to fetch the relevant [`Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).